# How to concatenate + tokenize + pad strings in TFX preprocessing?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-preprocessing, tensorflow-extended

I'd like to perform the usual text preprocessing steps in a TensorFlow Extended pipeline's Transform step/component. My data is the following (strings in independent features, 0/1 integers in label column):

```
field1 field2 field3 label
--------------------------
aa     bb     cc     0
ab     gfdg   ssdg   1
```

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tf_text
from tensorflow_text import UnicodeCharTokenizer

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    
    outputs = {}
    outputs['features_xf'] = tf.sparse.concat(axis=0, sp_inputs=[inputs["field1"], inputs["field2"], inputs["field3"]])
    outputs['label_xf'] = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs["label"], dtype=tf.float32)

    return outputs
```

but this doesn't work:

```
ValueError: Arrays were not all the same length: 3 vs 1 [while running 'Transform[TransformIndex0]/ConvertToRecordBatch']
```

(Later on I want to apply char-level tokenization and padding to `MAX_LEN` as well).
Any idea?

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? what is calling `preprocessing_fn`?

Comment: Other part of the context is quite standard TFX pipeline, with the Transform component referring to a python file with the preprocessing_fn() in it. It's all conventional.

Comment: Input is a CSV file (according my example) read by a standard CsvExampleGen() component. The information then flows downstreams through all the other out-of-box components.